# C# Xceed Unzip unzipping file according to list object data path

Tags: c#, sql

I have a list object in my application:

```
List<TestData> data = new ExportBM().GetData();
```

This list object contains an ImportDirectory field. I want to use Xceed Unzip to unzip the files in the ImportDirectory

so far I have the following:

```
    foreach (TestData item in data)
            {
                item.ImportDirectory
            }
```

What is the method in xceedd unzip to unzip the files according to a passed  filepath? Is there one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [`QuickZip.Unzip`](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/Xceedfilesystem/Xceed.Zip%7EXceed.Zip.QuickZip%7EUnzip%28String,String,String,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,DiskRequiredCallback,Object,String%5B%5D%29.html) what you're looking for? You might need something like:

```
foreach (TestData item in data)
{
   string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(item.ImportDirectory, "*.zip");
   foreach(string file in files)
   {
      QuickZip.Unzip(file, "c:\\", string.Empty, true, true, false, null, null, "*" ); 
   }    
}
```

**Edit**

I added examples of the rest of the arguments. The last being `filesToUnzip` which is a `params` that is looking for file paths within the archive to unzip. It allows you to do partial unzips explicitly or based on masks. In this case the mask `"*"` will be read as a wildcard and all files will be unzipped.

Comment: The problem with this is that the importdirectory is just the directory of the zip file, will this allow me to unzip everything in that directory?

Comment: Like there could be 6 zip files in each directory.

Comment: @user380432: I thought that might be what you need. I added the 'Directory.GetFiles' call. It will return an array of paths to files with a '.zip' extension in the 'ImportDirectory'. Then the internal 'foreach' will iterate through the file paths, calling 'Unzip' on each. Replace the "c:\\" with the destination for the unzipped contents.

Comment: If you need to extract just the directory from ImportDirectory call Path.GetDirectoryName and it will return just the directory. Also, the static classes Directory and Path are both objects in the System.IO Namespace. So remember to add a using System.IO statement.

Comment: When I do exactly how you stated I get this exception in the QuickZip.Unzip() method. 11/17/2010 11:08:14 - Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: filesToUnzip. I see the method takes an array element any idea what to do here?

Comment: @user380432: Sorry about that. I added additional information to my answer. Let me know if that helps.